# Do db.collection.replaceOne by spring data mongo

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I want to replace whole document in mongo collection in one update instead of "query and update".

It seems the [db.collection.replaceOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/) can do this job, but I can't find any api in the [MongoOperations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html).

Comment: did you check findAndModify method

Comment: the findAndModify api force the caller to update each field explicit, it is very painful.

Answer (score 2):

Just call [`save()` on `MongoTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#save-java.lang.Object-) which will invoke `replaceOne` with `UpdateOptions().upsert(true)`.