# Spring Data Mongodb replace whole document as json

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a Mongo db in Spring boot application (spring-data-mongodb is 2.1.5).

I want to update all documents by replacing their json. Get each one, modify it with jaskson and put back. Is it possible with using MongoTemplate or some other API in spring-data-mongodb?

Comment: I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768431/what-is-the-correct-method-to-update-a-document-while-using-mongo-cursor

Comment: In MongoDB there are two collection methods [findOneAndReplace](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndReplace/) and [replaceOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/) to replace a document. Spring's [MongoTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.17.RELEASE/api/) has the `findAndReplace` method.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49815728/5330655 , as he said just use save() on MongoTemplate